# Guardo una dirección en mysql (ej.https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) y cuando lo mando a llamar con php me regresa htpp:\/\/

Tags: php, android, mysql

En mi base de datos guardo direcciones de diferentes paginas web para después mandarlas a llamar y mostrarlas en un textview, o usar esa dirección para descargar el archivo que contiene esa dirección

Este es el PHP

```
<?php
include('functions.php'); 
$nombre=$_GET['nombre'];
if ($resultset = getSQLResultSet("SELECT Direccion FROM `tramites` where nombre='$nombre'")) {  
        while ($row = $resultset->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        echo json_encode($row);
        }
   }

?>
```

por ejemplo, guardo `" https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask "`
y cuando lo mando a llamar me regresa `" https:\/\/es.stackoverflow.com\/questions\/ask"` y así no puedo usar la dirección.

en mi codigo en Android Studio, uso el replace para quitar ese `"\/"` y dejar el `"/"` pero me pone que `"\"` es ilegal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que tu respuesta las estas pasado a JSON, lo que debes haces es usar `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`:

```
 echo json_encode($row,64);
```

[Referencia](http://php.net/manual/es/json.constants.php)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!, no sabía que tenía que usar eso, me funciono bien

Comment: ok no olvides puntuar la respuesta y aceptar la pregunta